# Asking about Codingbat Java

Tags: discussion

I am new to java programming and use codingbat.com to practice. However, the website doesn't seem to provide any solutions to their questions, so I wanted to ask for help in Stack Overflow. Is it okay for users to ask for help solving Codingbat questions? Does it go against any copyright rules, etc.?

Comment: Top tip: asking questions you know to be off-topic isn't a smart way to get more rep

Comment: @hyoo we can help you with specific issues you might encounter and can't solve on your own. We won't be solving exercises though.